# Batch files: ask for user input with "suggestions"

Tags: batch-file

How can I prompt users for an answer, suggesting something they can edit?
I know how to make a q&a like:

```
1. The sky is:
```

The user put the answer and:

```
echo For you the sky is %var%
```

But i want something like:

```
    1. The sky is: Blue

echo For you the sky is Blue
```

But the user can change it

```
1. The sky is: Green
echo For you the sky is Green
```

I don't know if i was clear, tell me if not.
Thanks

Comment: No - not clear - are you asking how to change "Blue" to "blue" or "Green" to "green"?

Comment: Not: I want a question and an default answer in the same line "The sky is: blue" but i want the user can change the word "blue" with another and save it in a variable, or leave the word "blue" as default

Comment: You cannot do this is in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the variable before with a color:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "color=Blue"
set/p "color=For you the sky is %color% (hit enter for o.k. or type in other color): "
echo For you the sky is %color%
```

Comment: Thanks, but again is another q&a in a classic way, i'd like to change the answer directly in the same line and not to see "For you the sky is Blue: Green"

Comment: You can't do this in batch without external programs.

Answer (score 1):

```
set x=blue
set y=
set /p "y=The sky is [%x%] "
if not defined y set y=%x%
echo For your the sky is %y%
```

If user input is empty, the predefined %x% is copied to the outputvariable %y%

Comment: I can't delete the [blue] variable in "The sky is [blue]", in this way it's a normal question - answer. Thanks

Comment: this can only be achieved by manipulating the keyboard-buffer. there is no way to do this with native methods - you need an external program or utiliy for that - or even better: programming the whole thing in a "real" programming language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WScript.Shell's [SendKeys method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) through JScript or VBScript to simulate keypresses.  Give this a shot.  I think it does what you're looking for.  It will send uneditable `1. The sky is:` then simulate the user keystrokes of <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.  The user is then free either just to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or he can <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase "Blue" and replace it whatever he wishes.

Save this with a `.bat` extension and run it.

```
@if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@echo off
setlocal

set /p "=1. The sky is: "<NUL
call :sendkeys Blue
set /p "sky="

echo For you the sky is %sky%.  Press any key to exit.
pause >NUL

exit /b

:sendkeys <string>
cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%~1"
goto :EOF

:: JScript portion */
var sh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
sh.SendKeys(WSH.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: What is `@if (@a==@b) @end /*` ?

Comment: The `@if (@a==@b) @end` line does exactly nothing, but the `/*` begins a multiline comment in JScript. See, it's a hybrid script, one script containing two languages. The batch half runs until `cscript thisfile.bat` re-runs the same script, but with a JScript interpreter. JScript evaluates the first line as false, all the batch code as a multiline comment, and starts working where it encounters the `*/` near the bottom of the script. The first line is the only line that is mandatorily evaluated by both batch and JScript, so it must be error-free in both.

Comment: I think that `@if (@CodeSection==@Batch)  ::batch portion...  @end` is clearer. The OP may assume (correctly) that these lines enclose a batch portion of a multi-language file even if they knows nothing about hybrid scripts and Jscript language. `@end` is a delimiter less prone to go unnoticed, like `*/`

Answer (score 0):

As other answers said, you must need a third party utility to solve this problem. For example, I used my GetKey.exe and Show.exe auxiliary programs to write ReadLine.bat, a subroutine that simulate `SET /P` command, that is, it read characters until Enter key is pressed and delete the last character with BackSpace key. We may modify such routine in order to provide an *initial value* for the input variable:

```
@echo off

rem Read a variable with an initialized value
rem Antonio Perez Ayala

set Bell=7
set BackSpace=8
set Enter=13
set Space=32

:ReadInitVar var="prompt" ["initial value"]
rem          %1   %2        %3

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Show %2
set len=0
if "%~3" equ "" (
   set %1=
) else (
   Show %3
   set "%1=%~3"
   for /L %%i in (0,1,80) do if "!%1:~%%i,1!" neq "" set /A len+=1
)

:nextKey
   GetKey
   set key=%errorlevel%
   if %key% geq %Space% (
      rem Ascii character: insert it
      Show %key%
      for /F "delims=" %%a in ('Show %key%') do set "%1=!%1!%%a"
      set /A len+=1
   ) else if %key% equ %BackSpace% (
      rem Backspace: delete last character
      if defined %1 (
         Show %BackSpace% %Space% %BackSpace%
         set "%1=!%1:~0,-1!"
         set /A len-=1
      ) else (
         rem Empty value
         Show %Bell%
      )
   )
if %key% neq %Enter% goto nextKey
echo/
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!%1!") do endlocal & set %1=%%a
exit /B
```

This way, you may use this line to solve your problem:

```
call :ReadInitVar color="For you the sky is " "Blue"
```

You may download Getkey.exe and Show.exe auxiliary programs, and review the original ReadLine.bat subroutine, from this site: [Advanced Batch features via auxiliary .exe programs](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3428).

There is also another subroutine similar to ReadInitVar.bat above, but that display the user input in a *different color field* by using ColorShow.exe auxiliary program instead of Show.exe. You may review it here: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4198&p=23426#p23426